# Can Apache Thrift use multiple transports for a single server?

Tags: thrift

I have a server with many lightweight methods and one heavyweight method. I can't seem to find evidence that Apache Thrift supports multiple transports for a server. What I'd like is shared memory for all but the heavyweight method and TCP/IP (distributed) for the heavyweight method. I could break it into two servers but that sort of breaks the goal of encapsulation (I think).

Comment: No, it can't. Why is the transport relevant? If the method is heavyweight I don't see how changing the transport will have any impact on the performance of that specific method.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's so slow it requires much more horsepower than the calling code. Let's say the application code is distributed over 20 servers. Local methods are so fast that remote execution would add significant overhead (so shared memory on each app server would be fine). The "slow" method can make use of huge, specialized,  multi-core nodes (and lots of them--say thousands as the application grows) so a distributed transport makes more sense for these--in fact it could never reasonably complete if restricted to the 20 nodes. Ratio of "slow" to "fast" methods: 100-1 at best.

Comment: I see. Did you consider using a cluster instead of doing this manually? This will let your 20 servers behave like they are one without you having to code it.

Comment: We may mean different things when we each say "cluster". I run on HPC clusters with severely restricted operating environments (Linux, Slurm, MPI only). I can't run things like Mesos, Aurora, AWS, load balancers, etc. I have to do it all by myself. Many HPC apps are static, but mine is elastic. So, I have to write scheduling, load balancing, etc. myself. Thrift looks like it will make that somewhat easier by providing an async/sync RPC capability. I may also try ZeroMQ for dynamic messaging (I can run TCP/IP over the HPC networks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really mean transports - not directly. What is possible is to have the handler as a separate entity that can be re-used, e.g. with a different protocol/transport stack.

As it sounds, the best solution in your case would indeed be to have two servers with two different protocol/transport stack, both using the same handler code, but implementing different Thrift services.

```
                              +----------------+
       +----- uses ---------> | LWService      | <-------+
       |                      +----------------+         |
       |                                             implements
       |                                                 |
+------+-----------+                               +-----+-----+
|                  |                               |           |
|                  |                               |           |
|  Client          |                               | Handler   |
|                  |                               |           |
|                  |                               |           |
|                  |                               |           |
|                  |                               |           |
|                  |                               +-----+-----+
+------+-----------+                                     |
       |                                              implements
       |                      +----------------+         |
       +---- uses ----------> | HeavyService   | <-------+
                              +----------------+
```

Comment: I will need to cogitate on this for a while. Thanks for the response.